# How detect launch NSIS installer with arguments

Tags: nsis

I have NSIS installer.
How detect launch NSIS installer with arguments?

For example `installer.exe /DEBUG`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GetOptions](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixE.html#E.1.12):

```
!include FileFunc.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Function .onInit
${GetParameters} $0
ClearErrors
${GetOptions} $0 "/DEBUG" $1
${IfNot} ${Errors}
    MessageBox mb_ok "Debug"
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```